# In midnight commander, how is a windows domain specified when making an smb connection?

Tags: smb, mc

Midnight commander allows making network connections to SMB services (if compiled with support for the SMB file system).

The help contents for detailing how to make an SMB connection are these

```
SMB File System                                                                 

The smbfs allows you to manipulate files on remote machines with SMB (or CIFS)  
protocol. These include Windows for Workgroups, Windows 9x/ME/XP, Windows NT,   
Windows 2000 and Samba. To actually use it, you may try to use the panel        
command "SMB link..." (accessible from the menubar) or you may directly change  
your current directory to it using the cd command to a path name that looks     
like this:                                                                      

smb://[user@]machine[/service][/remote-dir]                                     

The user, service and remote-dir elements are optional. The user, domain and    
password can be specified in an input dialog.                                   

Examples:                                                                       

    smb://machine/Share                                                         
    smb://other_machine                                                         
    smb://guest@machine/Public/Irlex
```

This seems to suggest the only way to enter a domain is via a popup dialog box.  Is there a way to specify a domain at the Midnight Commander command line?

I'm hoping for something like 'cd smb://username:domain@machine/share'.  Does anyone know if there's a way to specify the windows domain at the Midnight Commander internal command prompt?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming a reasonably recent version of mc, `cd smb://...` should be exactly the same as using the popup.

Comment: In this example string ( smb://[user@]machine[/service][/remote-dir] ) there's nothing that allows specifying a domain.  My question is how to extend this syntax to include the domain.

Comment: *"It would appear that the latest versions of mc don't have samba support, but it is planned to be included again in the future"*   http://www.trembath.co.za/mctutorial.html#anchor13

Comment: Building a version of midnight commander with SMB support from source is fairly straight forward with this recipe [https://superuser.com/questions/468663/install-mc-with-smb-support], although it's still not clear how to include the domain as a command line (non-dialog box) type parameter